# add the row in DataView at the last Position

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, dataview

I need to add the row in DataView at the last Position.
I have already used the Dv.Table.rows.InsertAt() but it sort the row by Specify column.

**I need some thing Like.**

- first i add the table in dataview and sort by specify column.
- then i need to add the column **at the end**(Added row should not be sort) of dataview without interrupting the already sort row.

**what is happening**

- when i add the value in Table in dataview it got sort by the specify column.
- Or if i add the value in dataview the first row added at end and from second rowadded at first..

Pleas help..

Answer (score 1):

You must sort the data outside of the Gridview, then put the data into the Gridview, without setting the sorting property of the Gridview. Then you can add the new row and it will be displayed at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. By no means this is a perfect solution. You can consider this until you get a good solution.

Here I am sorting the datatable which is to be binded to the grid not the datagridview itself.

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");

        dt.Rows.Add("3", "Entered 1st");
        dt.Rows.Add("1", "Entered 2nd");
        dt.Rows.Add("2", "Entered 3rd");
```

First sort the datatable. Copy it to another table using the defalutview.ToTable method and add the new row.

```
        dt.DefaultView.Sort  = "ID ASC";

        DataTable dtnew = new DataTable();
        dtnew = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();


        dtnew.Rows.Add("1", "Should be last row");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtnew;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the dataview in a datatable and add the last row after that:

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Column Name";
dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
dt.Rows.InsertAt(row,pos);
```